# Bijection of $\mathbb{R}^4$ onto hermitian matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Consider the hermitian matrices $H:=\{M\in\mathbb{C}^{2\times 2}|M=M^\dagger\}$ and the map $$\mathbb{R}^4\to H,(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)\mapsto\begin{pmatrix}x_1+x_4&x_2-ix_3\\x_2+ix_3&x_1-x_4\end{pmatrix}.$$

Is this map bijective?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is easy to show that it is injective. Let's show that it is surjective. If you take a Hermitian matrix $H$ and compute the complex transpose of $H$ then using the fact that $H$ is Hermitian, you can see that the diagonal entries are real and the anti diagonal entries are the conjugate of each other.

Now for any $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$ you can find $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $x=a+b$ and $y=a-b$ (just take $a=(x+y)/2$ and $b=(x-y)/2$). Using this fact, you can see that the map is surjective.

Comment: I understand your argument for the diagonal entries but not for the anti ones. Can you explain this please?

Comment: Every complex number is of the form $x+iy$. Then the conjugate of this element is $x-iy$. Hence you can write the anti diagonal entries as $x+iy$ and $x-iy$ since they are the conjugates of each other.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The surjectivity is clear because the diagonal element of an hermitian matrix are real, and the anti-diagonal elements conjugate to each other. As for the injectivity, assume

$$\begin{pmatrix}x_{1}+x_{4}&x_{2}-ix_{3}\\x_{2}+ix_{3}&x_{1}-x_{4}\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}y_{1}+y_{4}&y_{2}-iy_{3}\\y_{2}+iy_{3}&y_{1}-y_{4}\end{pmatrix}$$

In particular $x_{1}+x_{4}=y_{1}+y_{4}$ and $x_{1}-x_{4}=y_{1}-y_{4}$. Sum those two equations and get

$$2x_{1}=2y_{1}$$

Thus $x_{1}=y_{1}$ and $x_{4}=y_{4}$. Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 0):

Consider the function

$$ f\begin{pmatrix}a & b\\c & d\end{pmatrix} = \left(\frac{a+d}{2},\frac{b+c}{2},\frac{c-b}{2i},\frac{a-d}{2}\right). $$

Is this a collection of real numbers for all Hermitian matrices?